# React Native: Expo run project on android device

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I'm trying to run my react native project on an android device using expo, and this error page shows up. There are multiple similar questions regarding this, but they're all either outdated or they simply don't work. Anyone got any ideas?. Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Question, what is "this ugly hack" in the error message? It looks like some library is broken, that would be my guess.

Comment: that's what I'm wondering too. This is the first thing I did after installing react native. Didn't touch the code, package.json, or anything

Comment: Huh, never seen this before. Are you running `expo start` to get things going? How did you start your new project?

Comment: Are you creating a project using a template?

Comment: There is a difference between setting up firebase for Expo and React Native CLI, the problem is with your firebase installation. Uninstall the library and see if the project runs perfect. If so, then reinstall firebase and follow the guidelines properly.

Comment: there is 'firebase' in the project name, but I have not yet implemented it or done anything with it